# Viewport units in final keyframe of CSS animation not recalculating in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, css-animations, viewport-units

A box widens through a keyframe animation (iterations: 1, fill-state: forwards) from width: 10vw to width: 20vw (final keyframe). After the animation ends, the box is not responsive (upon window resize) in Safari. It works as expected in Chrome and Firefox.

I've tried using -webkit- prefix and splitting the animation properties, to no avail. I'm forced to use js to change CSS class after the animation ends (code after the snippet).

```css
.box {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  animation: widen 2s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes widen {
  0% {
    width: 10vw;
  }
  100% {
    width: 20vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="box-id" class="box"></div>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/foresto/pen/xxxwjoR) is a codepen with the js workaround commented out and the animation shorthand property split up: it still doesn't work as expected.
Here is the js workaround, which I'd like to get rid of:

CSS

```css
.box2 {
    width: 20vw;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("box-id").addEventListener('animationend', (e) => {
  e.target.classList.add("box2");
  e.target.classList.remove("box");
});
```

I found many questions related to safari and keyframes, but I couldn't find anything specific on responsive units. I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong, or if there's a known fix to this behaviour.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Safari does not read trough the shorthand method for describing the animation.

You can try:

```
.box{
     animation-name: widen;
     animation-duration: 2s;
     animation-timing-function: ease;
     animation-delay: 0s;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-direction: normal;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Comment: I added a [codepen](https://codepen.io/foresto/pen/xxxwjoR) with the js workaround commented out and the animation shorthand split up: unfortunately it still doesn't resize with the window